# javax.validation.ConstraintDefinitionException: HV000074

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, annotations

I am trying to use javax/hibernate custom validation on specific field, but I am getting the following error:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintDefinitionException: HV000074: com.hertz.digital.hertzrac.model.Code contains Constraint annotation, but does not contain a payload parameter.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.assertPayloadParameterExists(ConstraintHelper.java:427) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.isConstraintAnnotation(ConstraintHelper.java:407) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findConstraintAnnotations(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:582) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findConstraints(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:535) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findPropertyMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:234) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getFieldMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:227) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.retrieveBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:137) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:125) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getBeanConfigurationForHierarchy(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:108) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.createBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:203) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.getOrCreateBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:231) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.isConstrained(BeanMetaDataManager.java:174) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:194) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:118) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcValidator.validate(WebMvcValidator.java:69) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:891) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.validateIfApplicable(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:168) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:115) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter.doFilter(TraceFilter.java:153) [spring-cloud-sleuth-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

**Custom Interface**

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Constraint(validatedBy = {CustomValidator.class})
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Code {
    String message() default "Invalid Limit of Code";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] palyload() default {};


}
```

**Custom Validator**

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class CustomValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Code, String>{

    @Override
    public void initialize(Code constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String rewardRequest, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if(rewardRequest.length()<2)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Have followed reference doc, but still wasn’t able to resolve.

Answer (score 18):

The message is pretty clear:

> com.hertz.digital.hertzrac.model.Code contains Constraint annotation,
>   but does not contain a payload parameter

You just have a typo in your annotation class (`palyload` instead of `payload`).
Replace the line with

```
Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
```