# javax.validation.ConstraintDefinitionException: HV000074 in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have made a simple demo project for my students but I am not able to recognize this error following are the classes please let me know what I am missing.  
Interface

```
package ani.validator;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;

@Constraint(validatedBy={CourseCodeContstraintValidator.class})
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CourseCode {

    public String value() default "LUV";

    public String message() default "Not a proper code";

}
```

Custom Validation Class

```
package ani.validator;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class CourseCodeContstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CourseCode, String> {

    private String prefixCourseCode;

    public void initialize(CourseCode theCourseCode){
         prefixCourseCode = theCourseCode.value();
    }

    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext arg1) {

        if(prefixCourseCode != null){
            return value.startsWith(prefixCourseCode);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Your suggestions, comments are welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: Pease see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907817/javax-validation-constraintdefinitionexception-hv000074).

Comment: I didn't get any help  Branislav Lazic

Comment: @AnirudhJadhav It sounds like you may also be interested in checking out the [cseducators.se] community.

Comment: Where is the stacktrace?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got that error as well:

```
javax.validation.constraintdefinitionexception: hv000074
```

It's about `groups()` and `payload()` missing in your constraint annotation, just add those 2 lines and you should be good:

```
Class<?>[] groups() default {};
Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
```

Comment: This worked for me as well, but I didn't get it. Why is it necessary to add those attributes if they are not used?